# How do I align my output?

Tags: shell

I'm writing a script that takes a parameter and reads the output of `ls -l`. It then displays the user and the name of the file STARTING with that parameter.

For example :

```
$> ls -l | ./script.sh "o"
John        ok_test
RandomUser  o_file
```

My script works just fine, but I have one (minor) problem that I truly need to fix : it does not align the file names as in the example above.

Here is the said script :

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                   

while read hello
do
    name=$(echo $hello | cut -d' ' -f9 | grep "^"$1)
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        log=$(echo $hello | cut -d' ' -f3)
        echo -n -e $log'\t' && echo $name
    fi
done
```

Does anyone of you know a way to align the output no matter the size of the user name?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can pipe your output to `column -t`

Comment: So would it look like `echo -n -e $log | column -t && echo $name` ? The problem is it gives an output where there is a '\n' between the login and the file. Could you please show me what I should change in the script? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No, you pipe the entire output of the while loop: `while read hello; do ....; done | column -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rewrite that as:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -ra hello; do
    name=${hello[8]}
    if [[ $name == "$1"* ]]; then
        log=${hello[2]}
        echo "$log $name"
    fi
done | column -t
```

`read -ra` splits the input line and stores the words in the "hello" *array*.
`[[ $name == "$1"* ]]` is a built-in way to check if a string begins with some value.